# What script/program is used to create this style of image graphs?

Tags: image, graph, statistics, server, monitor

I see this same style of image graphs, usually .png that is used in many routers, CMS, control panels, etc, what actual script generates these ?

RRDtool

[image]

Plesk panel health monitor.
Edit: I see Plesk also uses rrdtool

[image]

Cacti graphs

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specific graph is generated with [RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/).

RRDTool is a round robin database for storing time series data. It also includes a tool to generate graphs from that data.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the one, thank you. I had another reply, I deleted it.